# Angular 4 - How to use same component as a child router of two different parent component?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

My question is about routing in angular.
I have a component `TelephonicConversationComponent`
which is a child router of `SearchProfileComponent`. I want to use the component (`TelephonicConversationComponent`) again in `JdTextSearchComponent`.

Basically, I have two tabs (`search-profile` and `jd-search`). Under `search-profile` tab I have two more tabs (`telephonic-conversation` and `schedule-meeting`). Under `jd-search` I have two tabs, one of them is `jd-text-search`. I want to re-use `telephonic-conversation` under `jd-text-search`.

Here is my a part of code,

```
`{path:"search-profile", component:SearchProfileComponent,children:[
   {path: '', redirectTo:'telephonic-conversation',pathMatch:'full'},
   {path:"telephonic-conversation", component:TelephonicConversationComponent},
    {path:'schedule-meeting',  component:ScheduleMeetingComponent},
 ]},
 {path:"jd-search", component:JdSearchComponent,children:[
   {path: '', redirectTo:'jd-file-search',pathMatch:'full'},
   {path:"jd-file-search", component:JdFileSearchComponent},
   {path:'jd-text-search',  component:JdTextSearchComponent},
 ]},`
```

How can I re-use `telephonic-conversation` under `jd-text-search`?

Comment: Can you just use it within `jd-text-search`? Do you want to use it via routing? I didn't quite understand the problem here.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "under" here. Do you mean as another child route? Or do you mean as a nested child component?

Comment: I want to use it as child route @Deborahk

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner child component which I am using for search-profile, I want to use the same for jd-text-search

Answer (score 1):

If you try to use a component, you can declare a selector in the @Component annotation

in the html of the component you want to inject your other component you can use your selector

EXAMPLE :

```
  @Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  templateUrl: './child-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child-component.component.scss']
  })
```

in your parent.component.html you can do this

```
<child-component></child-component>
```

Comment: In my parent.component.html selector,templateUrl and styleUrls are already defined. In that html I am doing other stuff and I also want to use child component f

Comment: you just have to add the selector of the child component no ? i don't understand your problem, can you make a stackblitz to help us understand ?

Comment: My preset @component is @Component({
  selector: 'app-jd-text-search',
  templateUrl: './jd-text-search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./jd-text-search.component.css']  
})  ..How can I use multiple selector? How can I add child component?

Answer (score 0):

Just to ensure we are on the same page with the terms ... A child component is a nested component that is contained within the template of a parent component.

So to display the child component within the parent, in the HTML for the jd-text-search.component.html, you would just use the selector from the child component:

```
<telephonic-conversation></telephonic-conversation>
```

That puts the component directly *within* the other component. (No routing).

Is that what you are asking?